# Search array of objects (two properties) for multiple restrains

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce

Before I ask the question, I apologise for the terrible title, but I cannot describe it any better.

I have an array of objects created this way:

```
var setitems = new Array();
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5000"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5050"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5042"});
```

Items and sets are in a many-to-many relationship.

And a simple string array like this:

```
var itemlist = new Array();
itemlist.push("5010");
itemlist.push("5020");
// itemlist = ["5010", "5020"];
```

I need to know which sets contain all items in itemlist.

In this example it should return 1000 and 1010.

Number of items per set is variable.

Number os items in itemlist is variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: The `= new Array()` part of `var itemlist = new Array();` is completely unnecessary if you're assigning to `itemlist` on the next line. Those two lines should be simply `var itemlist = ["5010", "5020"];`.

Comment: Sorry. It was just a bad copy for the example. It needs the array declaration since the items in itemlist are pushed individually and not set all at once like I did here.

Comment: I could try creating a dict(key,value) where key is the set, value is a counter. Then cycling through the object array, if item in contained by itemlist, increase counter. Then if counter = array length, add the set as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group your items by set and then check if some set includes every item of your itemList. Hope this helps.

```js
const setitems = [];
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5000"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5050"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5042"});

const itemlist = [];
itemlist.push("5010");
itemlist.push("5020");

const find = (arr, list) => {

    const grouped = arr.reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, [val.set]: (acc[val.set] || []).concat(val.item) }), {});

    return Object.keys(grouped).reduce((acc, val) => {
        
        if (list.every(item => grouped[val].includes(item))) acc.push(val);
        
        return acc;
        
    }, []);
};

console.log(find(setitems, itemlist));
```

Comment: Great. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instances:

```
// Get an array of Set instances for entries matching itemlist entries
const [first, ...rest] = itemlist.map(item =>
    setitems.filter(entry => entry.item === item)
            .reduce((s, entry) => s.add(entry.set), new Set())
);
// Get an array of the entries in the first of those Sets that also have entries in all the rest
const result = [...first].filter(set => rest.every(s => s.has(set)));
```

```js
const setitems = [];
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5000"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1000", item: "5050"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5010"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1010", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5020"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1020", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5040"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1030", item: "5030"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5041"});
setitems.push({set: "1040", item: "5042"});

const itemlist = [];
itemlist.push("5010");
itemlist.push("5020");

// Get an array of Set instances for entries matching itemlist entries
const [first, ...rest] = itemlist.map(item =>
    setitems.filter(entry => entry.item === item)
            .reduce((s, entry) => s.add(entry.set), new Set())
);
// Get an array of the entries in the first of those Sets that also have entries in all the rest
const result = [...first].filter(set => rest.every(s => s.has(set)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it latter (btw: if you copy paste the code above you can make a fully working snipet that's easily tested here).

Comment: @JoãoGomes - I did -- see the "Show code snippet" bit at the end, which shows the code in the answer working with the test data you provided.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution might use a two step approach.

In a first step one creates a map/table/registry of all possible "set" value lists.

The final step then produces the result. It creates a list of "set" identifiers where each related "set" value list contains every value of another provided value list.

An ES5 only code then might look like that ...

```js
var setItemList = new Array();
setItemList.push({set: "1000", item: "5000"});
setItemList.push({set: "1000", item: "5010"});
setItemList.push({set: "1000", item: "5020"});
setItemList.push({set: "1000", item: "5050"});
setItemList.push({set: "1010", item: "5010"});
setItemList.push({set: "1010", item: "5020"});
setItemList.push({set: "1010", item: "5030"});
setItemList.push({set: "1020", item: "5020"});
setItemList.push({set: "1020", item: "5040"});
setItemList.push({set: "1020", item: "5041"});
setItemList.push({set: "1030", item: "5040"});
setItemList.push({set: "1030", item: "5041"});
setItemList.push({set: "1030", item: "5030"});
setItemList.push({set: "1040", item: "5041"});
setItemList.push({set: "1040", item: "5042"});

var itemlist = new Array();
itemlist.push("5010");
itemlist.push("5020");


// ... with good old ES-5 do ...


// 1st part of solution ... create a map/table/registry of all possible "set" value lists.
//
function collectAndFillSetValueLists (registry, setItem) {
    var key   = setItem.set;
    var value = setItem.item;
    var list  = registry[key] || (registry[key] = []); // get or create a "set" item specific list.

    // if (!list.includes(value)) {
    if (list.indexOf(value) === -1) {

        list.push(value);
    }
    return registry;
}
var setItemsRegistry = setItemList.reduce(collectAndFillSetValueLists, {});

console.log('setItemsRegistry : ', setItemsRegistry);


// 2nd part of solution ... create a list of "set" identifiers where each related
// "set" value list contains every value of another provided value list.
//
function collectSetIdsThatsListsContainEveryValue(collector, setKey) {
    var list = collector.registry[setKey];
    if (collector.valueList.every(function (setValue) {

        return (list.indexOf(setValue) >= 0);
        // return list.includes(setValue);
    })) {
        collector.keyList.push(setKey)
    }
    return collector;
}
var setIdentifierList = Object.keys(setItemsRegistry).reduce(collectSetIdsThatsListsContainEveryValue, {

    registry: setItemsRegistry,
    valueList: itemlist,
    keyList: []

}).keyList;

console.log('setIdentifierList : ', setIdentifierList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```